# Solution for Javascript error '_events' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

Is any one has solution for JavaScript error `'_events' is null or not an object`?

Code is about 3000 line that's way I haven't put code here.Please Give me some hint so that I can put required code. I have searched on google and found two suggestion from google but not able to find solution.

I have tried latest version of AJAXControlToolkit.but not succeed.

I have trid `<compilation debug="true/false">`. but not succeed.

I am getting error on only one page.This page has Modelpopupextender and Radwindow and updatepanel.and error is in  `MicrosoftAjax.js` [image]

```
This error comes when 

Step1: Post back page.

Step2: redirect to other page or refresh same page. and error comes.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you google it there are many topics for that error. Also with out code its imposible to get real help.

Comment: Can you give us some code to demonstrate where the problem is?

Comment: Looks like something is missing from your page.  What are you trying to accomplish, maybe we can work through a scaled down block of sample code to figure out where the problem resides

Comment: @Jeff, I have updated image, It is telerik radgrid control’s datetime filter input control. When I save other records not related to this grid, still paste event of this datefiltercontrol called by default. and that causes error.

Comment: I need to understand more about what you are doing outside of the grid and the Date filter.  Something else on the page is causing this error

Comment: I recommend you post information about this error to the Telerik support forums.  Be sure to include some sample code about your problem.. this is not a constructive environment to resolve your unique problem.

Comment: @Jeff, okay thanks for you support,I will post to telerik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is,  DateFiltercontrol is in updatepanel, solution is I have to `set Postbacktrigger of updatepanel`.

Telerik support is saying don't use AJAXControlToolkit and Telerik control in same project. but I have used AJAXControlToolkit in code and not able to remove it.

So applied solution is set control which cause postback as `Postbacktrigger  of updatepanel`.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using the ModalPopupExtender to accomplish?  The RadWindow does much of the same functionality.

For what events in the grid are you triggering the popup window?

Given the following simple model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

}
```

and a GetForGrid method in my codebehind that looks like this:

```
public IQueryable<TestModel> GetForGrid()
{

    return new List<TestModel>
    {
        new TestModel {FileName="File1", CreateDate=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3), Type="Type1", UserName="user1"},
        new TestModel {FileName="File2", CreateDate=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2), Type="Type2", UserName="user2"},
        new TestModel {FileName="File3", CreateDate=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1), Type="Type3", UserName="user3"},
        new TestModel {FileName="File4", CreateDate=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2), Type="Type4", UserName="user4"},
        new TestModel {FileName="File5", CreateDate=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3), Type="Type5", UserName="user5"}
    }.AsQueryable();

}
```

I can create a RadGrid with the following markup, and it filters data properly:

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="grid" ItemType="WebApplication1.AjaxGrid.TestModel" 
    SelectMethod="GetForGrid" AllowFilteringByColumn="true"
    Width="100%">

</telerik:RadGrid>
```

-- I will update this answer as the discussion continues

Comment: I have multiple sections and each one in different updatepanel. May be second one is not updated and _Events=null becomes null.